# MariaDB cursor not working with Python Correctly

Tags: python, sql, mariadb, driver

I am having a problem with MariaDB.

When I use the following code in Python :-

```
print(maria)
a= maria.execute("select * from new_table")
print(a)
```

It prints :-

```
<MySQLdb.cursors.Cursor object at 0x000002020CB17BC8>
2
```

However, when I use MariaDB client in terminal, and use the following command :-

```
select * from new_table
```

I get the following :-

```
+------+------+
| aval | bval |
+------+------+
|   10 | Ok   |
|   20 | Kk   |
+------+------+
```

I have checked that I am using the same database in terminal as well as Python program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All [`execute`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) does is execute the query. You then need to `fetch` the data from the cursor, which you can do using (for example) [`fetchone`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchone.html):

```
maria.execute("select * from new_table")
row = maria.fetchone()
while row is not None:
    print(row)
    row = maria.fetchone()
```

Alternatively you can use the cursor as an iterator:

```
maria.execute("select * from new_table")
for row in maria:
    print(row)
```

Comment: That is very strange, because when I use `a= sql_server.execute("select * from new_table")` on a SQL server, I receive a `<class 'pyodbc.Cursor'>`, but in MariaDB, I receive an `<int>!`

Comment: Different driver I guess, I'm only familiar with the MySQL/MariaDB one...

Comment: According to https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15 return values for execute() are not defined.

Comment: @GeorgRichter Thanks for that link - I've only ever seen the MySQL docs. I guess if they're not defined that leaves it up to the driver writer. It would have been more helpful if they had specified a return value to avoid issues like this where one driver returns the cursor and another (seems to) return the number of rows.